# What type of charts are on the Remote Pilot exam?

Tags: regulations, faa

What type of aeronautical charts are on the remote pilot certificate exam? Are they VFR charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to he USA FAA Part 107 exam then yes, VFR charts.  You can download them here:  https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/